# How to add meta tag to mdBook?

Tags: rust, markdown, mdbook

I'd like to add [*Twitter Card*](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/cards/guides/getting-started) via `meta` tag to mdBook.

How can I add `meta` tags (example below) to mdBook?

```html
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"></meta>
```

Current workaround is to execute `sed` command after `mdbook build`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [*theme*](https://rust-lang.github.io/mdBook/format/theme/index.html) feature of mdBook.

1. Create a random mdBook with `--theme` option.

   ```bash
   $ mdbook init --theme abc
   ```
2. Confirm `theme/` directory is created.

   ```bash
   $ ls

   book  book.toml  src  theme
   ```
3. Copy `theme/` directory to your mdBook directory.
4. Edit `theme/index.hbs`.
5. Execute `mdbook build` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in https://rust-lang.github.io/mdBook/format/theme/index.html, you can specify a custom `head.hbs` file (which you can put into `theme/`) and add custom `<head>` tags to it.